# Change the time of a video when moving the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html

I stumbled across [this WoW website](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/warlords-of-draenor/) and, inspecting some elements, discovered that the "spinning characters" are WebM / MP4 videos. Go to the Characters section, pick a character, and press [this button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yfy9.png) This will load up a video of them spinning.

These videos can rewind and fast-forward depending on the direction you drag your cursor (Left = reverse, Right = fast-forward).

My question is simple, what function does that? Is it JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's indeed javascript. one cool link: http://emergeinteractive.com/demos/javascript-video-scrubber/

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian Hey thanks for that, but I checked out the files and they're just jpg frames. Unless I'm missing something out, I'm not too good of a coder.

Comment: OIC. Here's a better one: http://html5etc.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/a-basic-html5-video-scrub-bar-using-jquery/ Oh, but it certainly isn't easy. There will be a lot of coding.

Comment: @AdminVoter Have you ever figured out how was it done?

Answer (score 1):

It's JavaScript, and this is the code they are using:

```
//this is for video on stage
CharacterSelect.ui.modelVideo = ModelVideo.build($(".model-video"));

//and this is when the page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
if (ModelVideo.supportsVideo && !$('html').hasClass('ie')) {
  var modelVideo = videoController.create(".model-video");
}
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that just initialize the video? I'm still not too sure which part uses the mouse-dragging events.